Import LTSpice model
Does anyone know how to import to LTSpice this gate driver?
I downloaded the zip LMG5200 PSpice Transient Model (Rev. C) and put "lmg5200.lib" in the "sub" folder of LTSpice, then on LTSpice I included ".inc lmg5200.lib" and renamed with "lmg5200" a generic nmos. The problem is this:

In fact, if you open "lmg5200.lib," you will find a lot of confusion ... I didn't understand how to proceed.

Are you sure you grabbed the unencrypted file?

Yes. You need to use this file, not the first one in the list.  https://i.sstatic.net/UmkKuAiE.png

Use the unencrypted file: "LMG5200 Unencrypted Spice Transient Model". This is a PSpice model. LTspice can handle PSpice syntax, but not PSpice encrypted files.

thank you all, I downloaded that file and did again the procedure described in the main post. The problem is."can't find definition of model "lmg5200"" .. I used the directive ".inc lmg5200"

also, inside the file lmg5200.lib there are many .MODEL ... should I use one and delete the others? How does this work? It doesn't seem like a "normal" component like a classic op741, it is more complex and maybe its .lib provides more simulation models (?)

@KaleM It may be a bit of a process. The unencrypted version does include a lot of models. That's fine. But it means you will need to be careful and work out the bugs, as they exist, with care. It's probably not going to be cut-and-paste, as a guess. I'd start by creating a symbol for it and get all the pins labeled and set in place. Then I'd set the attributes and save the entire model file and link it to the symbol. Then I'd set up a quick-and-dirty schematic and see if I can even get an operating point result. If not, I'd debug it. Most things can be worked out if you look closely.

@KaleM  Hmmm...you should follow this guide to import your subcircuit:  https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html

@KaleM Have you resolved this? Or lost interest? There's a debugging process that you should find understandable when faced with lots of models/subcircuits like this. You apply them one by one and test each model, starting the simpler ones and moving towards increasing complexity, until you identify the offending one. If this doesn't happen until you get to the final one you are using then at least you know all the others work and can focus entirely on the last one to find the problem, trying out simpler versions or else just walking through it to create a schematic for it using the rest.

I was able to solve it. First of all thanks to your help for making me download the correct file. Also the downloaded .lib file Contains inside many templates that you can use. I chose the one I needed and created a new symbol. I was not really aware that the .lib file could contain so many templates and subcircuits

I don't know if there is a way to mark this question as resolved "resolved"

@KaleM I'll write an answer you can vote on and accept.

It seems like you have two problems here.  First, you're downloading the encrypted PSpice model and trying to use that in LTspice.  It's not your fault since it's not explicitly specified in the name.  Anyway, you can only use PSpice encrypted models within PSpice and not any other software.  You need to download the "Unencrypted" SPICE model, which is further down in the list.

Second, it sounds like you're not properly importing the model/subcircuit into LTspice and referencing it.  The easiest way to import 3rd party models is to follow this guide, which auto-generates a symbol for you containing a reference to the .lib file:
https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html
